# Stopping leading observations once certain threshold met in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hopefully this will make sense. In short, what I have is a pt with multiple encounters. Starting with the first encounter (and is always included) and then including the next encounter if within 4 hrs.
If the next encounter does not meet criteria then all other observations will not be included in the output-

The code below shows the problem. It outputs rows 1,2, and 4. I want rows 1&2 but not 4.
Any tips appreciated on this
TIA

```
With Base as 
(select 123 as ID, 12345 as enc_id, TO_DATE('2019-07-01 13:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as dt from dual union
 select 123 as ID, 12346 as enc_id, TO_DATE('2019-07-01 16:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as dt from dual union
 select 123 as ID, 12347 as enc_id, TO_DATE('2019-07-02 16:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as dt from dual union
  select 123 as ID, 12348 as enc_id, TO_DATE('2019-07-02 18:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as dt from dual)

select * from (select ID,ENC_ID,dt,row_number() over (partition by ID order by DT) RK,
lag(dt) over (partition by ID order by dt) prev_dt,
(DT-lag(dt) over (partition by ID order by dt))*24 as time_dif_hrs from base) where RK=1 or TIME_DIF_HRS<4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another analytical function `sum` as follows:

```
Select ID,ENC_ID,dt from
(select ID,ENC_ID,dt,rk,
        sum(case when (date - prev_date)* 24 < 4 then 0 else 1 end) 
                over( partition by ID order by DT) as cond_met_running 
  from (select ID,ENC_ID,dt,
               row_number() over (partition by ID order by DT) RK,
               lag(dt) over (partition by ID order by dt) prev_dt 
         from base)
       )
) Where rk = 1 or cond_met_running = 0
```

Comment: interesting. the var cond_met_running keeps starting at 1 even when I adjust for the missing prev_dt but that's ok I think I can use it all the same. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome @LawrenceBlock. Happy that you found the way of doing it using this solution.